# Get position of splitted windows on a vim editor

Tags: vim

I've been trying to find out how the get the position/coordinates of a splitt window inside a vim editor window, but no luck so far.

Say for example I have this layout

```
     (0,0)         (2, 0)           
       \____________/____________
       |            |          |
       |  Split A   |  Split C |
 (0,2)-+------------+----------+
       |  Split B   |  Split D |
       |____________|__________|  #Split D would be (2, 2)
```

I want to get the coordinates of the different splits on of my Vim Window, is this possible?

---

I've done my homework and googled this, also went through the vim `:help`/`:helpgrep`

Things that I've tried that wouldn't work:

- `getwinposx()`/`getwinposy()`: They doesn't work on terminal, and they don't actually return the info I want, it just returns the position of the Host OS window.
- `:winpos`: the same reason as the previous bullet.

Comment: What is the reason you want the splits for, there could be an easy way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to get the relative position of each split, so that I can resize them effectively... in order to get the relative position (A is on the Left of C, B is bellow A), I need those coordinates.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? (I mean in general, what problem are you trying to solve that you need this position)? Maybe it can be approached from another direction.

Comment: My answer [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7158/390) includes code you can use to fetch the OFFSET coordinates of the windows in the current tab (using the vim python interface)

Answer (score 4):

I do not know a function that will do this, but here are some facts:

1. Window size can be obtained using `winwidth(wnr)` and `winheight(wnr)`.
2. Number of windows can be obtained using `winnr('$')`.
3. If `0<wnr≤winnr('$')`, then window with number `wnr` exists.
4. Total width is `&columns` and total height is `&lines`.
5. Windows are separated by one-column or one-line separator.

<del>In order to get window layout you lack only one fact here: how windows are numbered. I can't find this in help now.</del>

```
:h CTRL-W_w
```

states that windows are numbered from top-left to bottom-right. It is not enough though to determine how windows will be numbered after executing the following commands:

```
only
enew
vnew
new
wincmd h
new
" Result:
" +---+---+
" | 1 | 3 |
" +---+---+
" | 2 | 4 |
" +---+---+
only
enew
new
vnew
wincmd j
vnew
" Result:
" +---+---+
" | 1 | 2 |
" +---+---+
" | 3 | 4 |
" +---+---+
```

Thus, it looks like determining current window layout is not possible without using window movement commands (`wincmd h/j/k/l`).

---

Some time ago one additional variant was introduced: `pyeval(printf('(lambda win: [win.col, win.row])(vim.windows[%s - 1])', winnr))` (also `py3eval(…)`) will provide exact position of the top-left corner of window `winnr`. Requires Vim compiled with `+python[/dyn]` or `+python3[/dyn]` and Python itself.

Comment: This blows because window movement commands invoked from a script are SLOW (hundreds of ms)

Comment: @StevenLu I have added also solution that uses Python support. In Neovim you may also use msgpack-rpc API.

Comment: Oh I see, in python a window structure is exposed? This might be the silver bullet I need. Curses! I thought I was finally finished working on this tweak. It's going to subsume the remainder of this weekend now.  (edit: OK, I re-read your comment, you said *also*, so you're pointing out that a way to architect my plugin may be to use that modern neovim capability)

Comment: @StevenLu For window movement commands you may need to use `:noautocmd` to make them less slow. This is in any case good idea because this should avoid some possible side-effects (though make sure that you return to the window you started iterating from *and* before returning to it you moved to the “previous” window (see `:h CTRL-W_p`)).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the `:noautocmd` tip! Another little trick that should help a lot.

Comment: I was using `exe startwin.'wincmd w'` to return to the original starting window. [See here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7158/390) for what I'm using this capability for.

Comment: Holy crap, ZyX! your :noautocmd trick brought a 100x speedup. It completely eliminates the problem of `wincmd` commands being time consuming. I guess I will still finish implementing my magic tiling height computations in python but I can definitely now run the entire routine from an often-run autocmd such as `WinEnter`. I really wish vim's profiler would show time taken by autocmd executions.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the only thing that might help you is:

```
:!xwininfo -id $WINDOWID
```

Other then that I don't think you can get the specific coordinate splits.

Comment: The question likely about vim split windows, not the X window.

Comment: Yea you're probably right but the information could be helpful.  By the way a vim expert from Annapolis... we should be best friends.

Comment: Yes, Randy Morris is right, I actually want the internal coordinates of the splits, not the position of the window, I can get that with `getwinposx()`/`getwinposy()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming across this question in September 2023, which now has the built-in function `winlayout()`, which appears to have been added into Vim circa 2019 judging from the [Vim's GH repo](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Avim%2Fvim%20winlayout&type=code).

Granted, its return value isn't exactly in the form the OP asked for. But for my purpose of determining if the primary split of my windows is along the vertical or horizontal orientation, this function suffices.