# Write a command to increase or decrease the number of vertical splits

Tags: vim

I usually have my Vim screen split into two vertical windows, each of which may be further horizontally split.  Sometimes, I want to add or delete a vertical window.  Is there a way to detect how many top-level vertical splits there are and add or remove vsplits as necessary?

For example, suppose my screen looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+
|        |        |
|        |        |
+--------+        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        +--------+
|        |        |
+--------+--------+
```

I want `:Columns 1` to give me

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

by closing the two right-most windows.

I want `:Columns 2` to do nothing, detecting that two columns are already open.

And I want `:Columns 3` to give me

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
+--------+        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        +--------+        |
|        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I am fine if the function ignores vertical splits within horizontal splits.  For example, if I had

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
+---+----+
|   |    |
|   |    |
|   |    |
|   |    |
+---+----+
```

and I ran `:Columns 2`, I would get

```
+--------+--------+
|        |        |
|        |        |
+---+----+        |
|   |    |        |
|   |    |        |
|   |    |        |
|   |    |        |
+---+----+--------+
```

Comment: What is there to gain with a complicated command that can't be done with a few `<c-w>s`/`<c-w>v` to add splits and `<c-w>c` to close splits?

Comment: According to [this SO comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8104454/955926), there doesn't seem to be a way to get relative positions of the splits without moving around between them and keeping track of things as you go. That said, `<C-w>n<C-w>L` will create a new split on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Do the files in the splits have anything in common? For example, are they from NERDTree or are all files in the same column from the same directory?

Comment: @PeterRincker, the gain is that, after splitting or unsplitting, the command would `:set columns=81*NVSPLITS-1` where `NVSPLITS` is the number of top-level vsplits.  I didn't ask about it in the question because it is easy enough for me to add later.  I do the splits manually now, but setting the columns is a bit a pain.

Comment: @Daan, no, they are arbitrary windows.

Comment: @MarkLodato I believe Gary is right. You will have to cycle through the windows. You should look into the following: `:h 'ea'`, `:h windows`, `:h window-functions`, and `:h window-sizing-functions`.

Comment: I suppose if you only use a limited amount of mappings to create and destroy the splits you could keep track of them. It is also theoretically possible to use `:mksession` and parse the output. But there doesn't seem to be any good way of doing it.

Comment: you've probably written a small plugin spec here. But I don't understand what you mean by `:set columns=81*NVSPLITS-1`. Are you not using full screen? Otherwise this doens't make sense.

Comment: @mihai, I am using gvim, and I want the size of the "gvim window" (i.e. the desktop window) to grow or shrink such that each "vim window" (i.e. panel within vim) has exactly 80 columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a way, but it is involved; the first step is to count the currently-open vertical windows, and I don’t know of any built-in function that facilitates this. The working approach I found to it is basically to start at the first window (the top of the first — if not the entirety of the first — vertical split), and to then, using `wincmd l`, move to the next window to the right for as long as `wincmd l` moves to a new window, adding each to a count of open vertical windows including the first one. (I think this is what Gary Fixler referred to in the comments on the question.)

I started trying to write the code for posting here, and it grew to become larger than any function I would want to put in my `~/.vimrc`, so I ended up turning it into a plugin which takes the above approach and provides the `:Columns` command; see [Columcille](https://github.com/fifthposition/columcille) (on vim.org at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4742.) The plugin also provides a command for similarly managing horizontal split windows: `:Rows` divides the current column (or the main window, if there are no open vertical splits) into the specified number of “rows.”